# php sessions with slim+twig, A template that extends another one cannot have a body

Tags: php, session, twig, slim

I'm making a website with twig and slim, and ran into some problems when trying to setup a user authentication system.

I am using a standard LAMP configuration (mysql, php5, apache2), along with composer, twig and slim.

I read trough [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html) tutorial and figured I'd do something similar, but don't know how to implement it into my application. What I'm having problems with is the `php sessions` part. So far I've only used `php` with `PDO` for my database connection (I made `POST` calls with `AJAX` to my .php files), but now it seems that I actually need to insert `php` code into my `twig` files.

so I tried to do this:

```
{% extends 'main.twig' %}

<?php
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();
/*** set a form token ***/
$form_token = md5( uniqid('auth', true) );
/*** set the session form token ***/
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
?>

{% block title %}
Sign Up | PTC Testers
{% endblock title %}

{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
{% endblock stylesheet %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="40" placeholder="john@example.com">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" value="" maxlength="20" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="&rarr; Login" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

and get the following error: `A template that extends another one cannot have a body in "signup.twig" at line 2.`

As this is the first time I'm doing anything like this, I have no idea how to proceed, and what the proper way to do this is. Any input is appreciated.

If you need more info about my app, configuration and whatnot, [here's a github repository of the project](https://github.com/Shooshte/PTC_Php). The relevant files are in `db_queries`, `templates` and in the root folder (`index.php`).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/sessions/native/):

> A Slim application does not presume anything about sessions. If you prefer to use a PHP session, you must configure and start a native PHP session with session_start() **before you instantiate the Slim application**.

Also instead of putting in the template which is not possible, what you actually need is a [**middleware**.](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/)

This means in index.php, your code would look something like:

```
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));

$csrfTokenGenerator = function () {
    $form_token = md5( uniqid('auth', true) );

    $_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
};

$app->get('/login', $csrfTokenGenerator, function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('login.twig');
})->name('login');
```

That said, Slim have already provided this functionality for you as a separate package - [Slim-Csrf](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf) - which is worth checking out.